# Groovy dynamic query from String to findAll on a collection

Tags: groovy, collections, closures

I have an app that receives a String query like so

```
"age >= 21"
```

Using this string param i need to filter a collection. Is there any way to do this with Groovy `findAll` or something else? I've tried the below but it just returns the entire list:

```
String query1 = "it.age >= 21"

println list.findAll { it -> query1 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def list = [[age:20],[age:23],[age:19],[age:21]]
def query = "it.age >= 21"
def sh = new GroovyShell()
def closure = sh.evaluate("{it -> $query}")
​println list.findAll(closure)​
```

Note that `it ->` isnt optional in this case, as the closure needs to know that it accepts an argument